# What is the difference between _chagrin_ and _dismay_?

Tags: differences

When would both be appropriate and when would only one be appropriate? How much do they overlap?

Comment: They overlap ***a lot***, so you'd need to give a specific context to decide which *might* be more suitable. But note that [***chagrin** is much less common*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+his+chagrin%2Cto+his+dismay&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20his%20chagrin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20his%20dismay%3B%2Cc0) - and in some contexts will more strongly imply ***guilt / regret*** (at something ***you did***), rather than ***consternation*** (because of things done ***to you***, or simply "happenstance").